# Concurrency send data by POST in TYPO3 show a blank page and are not save

Tags: php, concurrency, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have a large form, a complex survey (domain object in my extension) in TYPO3 but when there are many users that send the form or load a file (.xlsx) with the survey format (load many surveys) in same time by POST; they can not persistence their data in database and system show later time a blank page with the usual message "Page is being generated" . I know this page appears while create page cached, but how is the correct way for send information by POST to a page that does not cached.

Otherwise when there are unique user, this can send information the system is slow but the data are saved in database.

How could resolve this issue about the concurrency and save the information of all users that do it at same time.

I am using TYPO3 7.6 and PHP 5.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the target page or plugin the POST parameters will be sent to to non-cached. I think you have an Extbase action handling the request. In the `ext_localconf.php` you can set this action to non-cached. This should work.